# Changing render visibility of multiple nested collections

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, visibility

I have many nested collections with some suffixes as below

[Main Collection 1]

-[Sub Collection 1]

--[Sub Collection 1 ON]

--[Sub Collection 1 OFF]

-[Sub Collection 2]

--[Sub Collection 2 ON]

--[Sub Collection 2 OFF]

I need a script that finds all the collections that are ending with -ON- and turn their render visibility off, and then finds all the collections that are ending with -OFF- and turn their visibility on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the collection's property `hide_render` to toggle render visibility

[image]

```
import bpy

OFF = False

def contains_word(s, w):
    return (' ' + w + ' ') in (' ' + s + ' ')

for c in bpy.data.collections:
    if contains_word(c.name, "ON"):
        c.hide_render = OFF
    elif contains_word(c.name, "OFF"):
        c.hide_render = not OFF
```

Comment: i updated the answer can you check if that works for you? there is also an approach using regular expressions. but this should do for now :)

Comment: or `c.name.endswith("ON")`